# In-place find-and-replace by line (linux)

Tags: linux, sed

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
>ID1_ID2 other_stuff
more_other_stuff
>ID3_ID4 other_stuff
more_other_stuff
```

I'd like to change this into:

```
>ID1_ID2;label=ID1 other_stuff
more_other_stuff
>ID3_ID4;label=ID3 other_stuff
more_other_stuff
```

That is, for every line that starts with `>`, add `;label=ID` (in a specific position) where `ID` is the number between the `>` and the first underscore. All the IDs are integers.

I could figure this out in Python but is there any easy way to do this in-place with `sed` or `awk` or other Unix commmand line tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed you can use this:

```
sed -r 's/^>(([0-9]+)_([0-9]+))( .*)/\1;label=\2\4/' yourfile
```

If it works, you can add the option `-i,bak`.

It matches

- a line stating with `>` (`^>`)
- followed by two sequences digits
- separated by a `_`: `(([0-9]+)_([0-9]+))`

  - the whole sequence is captured into `\1`
  - each number is captured in to `\2`  and `\3`
  - the rest of the line (`( .*)`) is captured into `\4`
- the replacement makes use of the captured values to get what you want

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. And looking at it, I even get what it's doing!

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed:

```
$ sed -r 's/>([^_]+)\S+/&;label=\1/' file
>ID1_ID2;label=ID1 other_stuff
more_other_stuff
>ID3_ID4;label=ID3 other_stuff
more_other_stuff
```

add the `-i` flag once you've tested it.